# store all selected values from checkedlistbox to database

Tags: c#, npgsql, checkedlistbox

Im making a windows form in c# wherein all the values in checkedlistbox will store to database. The code actually works however:

1. only the last value checked is store repeatedly on the database just like the data below
2. employee id (id) on the table `famhistory` wont appear as a foreign key but it appears on the table `name` just like the data below

Table: `famhistory`

```
famid           famcon          id
30              stroke
31              stroke
32              stroke
```

Table: `name`

```
eid             name
2010-0244       Jam Lagcao
```

Can somebody please help me on how to solve my problems? thank you very much for your help.

Below is my code in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Npgsql;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form6_Load;
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into name(eid, name) Values (@eid, @name)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
            conn.Open();

            foreach (DataRowView view in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into famhistory (famcon) Values (@famcon)", conn);
                string value = view.Row[0].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(view[checkedListBox1.ValueMember].ToString());  
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famcon", checkedListBox1.SelectedValue);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM condition", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt.TableName = "condition";
            da.Fill(dt);
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;
            checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "conname";
            checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "conname";
            checkedListBox1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
            string[] condition = dt.Rows[0]["conname"].ToString().Split(',');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a value variable and never use it.

Comment: @dbugger sorry but i dont get what you mean

Comment: This is probably what you meant to save to the database... string value = view.Row[0].ToString(); But you never do a thing with it.

Comment: yes. but i dont have any idea on how to use it actually. can you give an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change your insert operation code to `famhistory` table like below

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
  NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into famhistory (famcon) Values (@famcon)", conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famcon", item.ToString());
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Not sure why you were using `DataRowView view` in `foreach` statement; that's wrong.

Also, see I am using `item.ToString()` instead of `checkedListBox1.SelectedValue` which will get you the last selected value only.

Comment: im using DataRowView  because if i dont use it, only System.Data.DataRowView will appear in my table

Comment: NO, you certainly don't need to use that.

Comment: i tried to use your code now but only System.Data.DataRowView will appear in my database table instead of checkedlistvalue.